# How to use Contains with Guid?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to get all enities from a context that are within a collection. While it works this way:

```
Ticket ticket = context.Tickets.Where(p => p.TicketId == ticketId);
ticket.Tasks.Where(p => !message.Tasks.Select(t => t.Id).Contains(p.Id));
```

it end in a  exception this way

```
context.Tasks.Where(p => message.Tasks.Select(t => t.Id).Contains(p.Id));
```

Please Note that `Id` is of Type `Guid`

**My Question is how can I write the second query to get all Tasks from the context that are within the message.Tasks collection?**

Edit

**NotSupportedException**

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'DataObjects.KeyValueDataObject`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

And the class

```
public class KeyValueDataObject 
{ 
    public TKey Id { get; set; } 
    public TValue Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Implemented as `KeyValueDataObject<Guid,String>`

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Linq-to-Entities needs to convert your list into a constant expression in order to turn your `Contains` into an `IN` statement, which may not work with GUIDs

Try extracting the lookups into a "constant" list first:

```
var lookup = message.Tasks.Select(t => t.Id).ToList();
context.Tasks.Where(p => lookup.Contains(p.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var tasks = context.Tasks.ToList().Where(p => message.Tasks.ToList().Any(t => t.Id.Contains(p.Id)));
```

I hope this help

code EDITED

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it ends in `Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<KeyValueDataObject<System.Guid,string>,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type`

I guess it is because of the generic datatype?

Comment: Yes, maybe. Why don´t you try converting the Id's to string, instead of trying to work with the Guids itself?  SOmething like KeyValueDataObject<String,String>

Comment: Well that ends in `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Guid>'`

Comment: mm, maybe with the edited code I wrote. Converting ToList both parts, but.. I am not so sure, only guessing and trying to help you at this point.

Comment: You're right! I selected the fasted one as correct. anyway You got my +1

Comment: Thanks bro! ;) I am glad to help, or at least to try!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var taskIds = message.Tasks.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray();
context.Tasks.Where(p => taskIds.Any(t => t.Id == p.Id));
```

Comment: No :( still the same exception

Comment: I did not realize Tasks was a KeyValuePair. Updated my answer now.

Comment: You're right! I selected the fasted one as correct. anyway You got my +1