# Strange Issue With GUID Search using C#

Tags: c#, blazor, abp

I'm trying to learn to use ABP with Blazor and MongoDB. I've got a set of objects in a database that I display as a list but I also want to be able to retrieve objects from the database by the object's GUID and this is where I'm running into problems.

This is the task I wrote to retrieve objects based on a filter from the database:

```
    private async Task GetObjectAsync(string filter)
    {
        var result = await ObjectAppService.GetListAsync(
            new GetObjectListDto
            {
                MaxResultCount = PageSize,
                SkipCount = CurrentPage * PageSize,
                Sorting = CurrentSorting,
                Filter = filter
            }
        );
        ObjectList = result.Items;
        TotalCount = (int)result.TotalCount;
        errorVal = TotalCount.ToString();
```

This is my GetListAsync() method where I retrieve objects from the database according to the filter string:

```
    public async Task<PagedResultDto<ObjectDto>> GetListAsync(GetObjectListDto input)
    {
        if (input.Sorting.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            input.Sorting = nameof(Object.Payload);
        }

        var objects = await _objectRepository.GetListAsync(
            input.SkipCount,
            input.MaxResultCount,
            input.Sorting,
            input.Filter
        );

        var totalCount = input.Filter == null
            ? await _objectRepository.CountAsync()
            : await _objectRepository.CountAsync(

** SEARCH METHODS GO HERE **


        return new PagedResultDto<ObjectDto>(
            totalCount,
            ObjectMapper.Map<List<Object>, List<ObjectDto>>(objects)
        );
    }
```

These are the search methods I've been trying:

```
object => object.Name.Contains(input.Filter));

object => object.Id.ToString().Contains(input.Filter));

object => object.Id.Equals(Guid.Parse(input.Filter)));
```

The first search method (search by name and return any DB results which contain it) works perfectly except for the fact I want to be able to search by GUID. The second search method would be ideal except it throws an exception when I use it:
(System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter: {document}{_id}.ToString().Contains("70f35018-a504-89f1-51c0-3a04cb49cb97").).

The third search method definitely retrieves something from the database (I have verified) but it doesn't display this result on the page for some reason and I obviously have to enter a complete GUID to return the object (not ideal).

I'm sure this is possible and I'm doing something wrong here but I'm not sure what that is. Can anyone tell me the correct way to search by GUID here? I expected Id.ToString().Contains(Filter) to work.

**UPDATE:**
I've sort of solved this problem - I needed to look at the MongoObjectRepository.cs file:

```
    public async Task<List<Object>> GetListAsync(
        int skipCount,
        int maxResultCount,
        string sorting,
        string filter = null)
    {
        var queryable = await GetMongoQueryableAsync();
        return await queryable
            .WhereIf<Object, IMongoQueryable<Object>>(
                !filter.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                obj => obj.Id.Equals(filter)
            )
            .OrderBy(sorting)
            .As<IMongoQueryable<Object>>()
            .Skip(skipCount)
            .Take(maxResultCount)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

For some reason, I was filtering based on the `Payload` property rather than `Id`.

I'm still confused, however, why `obj => obj.Id.ToString().Contains((filter))` doesn't work - is this not allowed when retrieving items from a database? I've tried this on `DateTimeOffset` fields as well (e.g. `obj => obj.InsertTimestamp.ToString().Contains((filter))`) and get similar problems. When I try to add the `.FirstOrDefault()` to the end of the `.WhereIf<Object, IMongoQueryable<Object>>()` statement it invalidates the function (has to be chained with all the other methods - maybe that's the problem there?)

Comment: I don't know what database you are using but for performance reasons `Equals` is superior to `Contains`. It's sounds like the third method retrieves fine but you're having some other issue with presentation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, he also specified he preferred the second option because he would like to retrieve the solutions by specifying a partial Id and not a complete Id.

Comment: Your reinventing the wheel use ODATA.

Comment: The code here is an API directly to a SQL database. How does putting a REST API in the middle make this any simpler?

Comment: I have to say I have not encountered the use case where people are entering and searching on partial GUID's.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747104/how-to-use-contains-with-guid

Comment: Maybe create a Guid with prefix+zeroes, and calculate the next prefix. Then `object.Id.CompareTo(guidPrefix) > 0 && object.Id.CompareTo(nextGuidPrefix) < 0`. Not sure if that's supported either

Comment: I just ran this and it works... `chatService.MessagesAsQueryable().Where(a => a.Id.ToString().Contains(searchstring)).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'd be happy to use `Equals` but it doesn't return the record for some reason (I do know that it's detecting the record if a correct GUID is entered).  I don't know exactly what you mean about inserting a REST API in the middle of my code - is that what I've done? I'd love to understand more about what you're talking about.

Comment: @BrianParker I wasn't able to attach `FirstOrDefault()` to my search method

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I took a look at that link, would that make things less efficient? It looks like they're taking everything from the DB as a list and then searching it?